# CloudKit: notificationChangedBlock no response

Tags: ios, objective-c, cloudkit, ckfetchnotificationchange

I working in app using CloudKit. I'm implement a way to get deltas from CloudKit to my app (I'm using the public database). I get a response back from fetchNotificationChangesCompletionBlock block but I don't get a response back from notificationChangedBlock.

Here is my code:

```
-(void)checkForNewData
{
    CKServerChangeToken *token = [[cloudKitToken helper] getCloudKitToken];
    CKFetchNotificationChangesOperation *op = [[CKFetchNotificationChangesOperation alloc]
                                               initWithPreviousServerChangeToken:token];
    NSMutableArray *noteIds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    op.notificationChangedBlock = ^(CKNotification *note)
    {
        CKNotificationID *noteId = note.notificationID;
        [noteIds addObject:noteId];

        if([note isKindOfClass:[CKQueryNotification class]]) {
            CKQueryNotification *qNote = (CKQueryNotification *)note;
            CKRecordID *changedRecordID = qNote.recordID;

            NSLog(@"I got CKQueryNotification");

        }

    };

    op.fetchNotificationChangesCompletionBlock = ^(CKServerChangeToken *token, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"error %@", error.localizedDescription);
    };

    [[CKContainer defaultContainer] addOperation:op];
}
```

Any of you knows what I'm doing wrong or what is wrong with my code?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Maybe stupid question, but have you registered listening to this notification  via `NSNotificationCenter` (perhaps in alloc/init) ?

Comment: @markich can you explain more in detail

Comment: my bad, wasn't reading clear enough. Anyway, I can't find anything wrong with that, except that: Are you 100% sure you get push notification AND this block doesn't get called?

Comment: If `notificationChangedBlock` isn't called it means that there have been no notifications since the token you passed in.

Comment: @rmaddy the old token is null because is the first time I made the request and is data to be download from cloudkit

Comment: Do I need to create a subscription (CKSubscription) ?

Comment: Subscriptions are the only way you get cloud kit notifications.

Comment: @rmaddy do you have an example of how to create the subscription in public database ?

Comment: There's one in the cloud kit user guide.

Comment: you might corrupted something in your container, create and check out a new container